# Set GStreamer videomixer to not wait for data from all Sources

Tags: linux, gstreamer

I have the following GStreamer Pipeline, which takes a videostream from the UDP and renders an overlay with a custom pluign (myoverlayrendererplugin), which is derived of the GstPushSrc Class:

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
   videomixer name=mix ! videoconvert ! \
      video/x-raw,width=800,height=480,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1 ! xvimagesink \
   udpsrc do-timestamp=false port=8554 ! decodebin ! \
      videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=800,height=480,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1 !  mix.\
   myoverlayrendererplugin ! video/x-raw,format=ARGB,width=800,height=480 ! mix.
```

Individually both streams are shown correctly. When mixing, the pipeline is only playing (i.e. the final XWindow with the composed image is opened) only when both streams are active, i.e. the udpsrc reads data. When I don't use the videoscale plugin, the output is activated even when no data is coming, but the input is always shown on top of the rendered image instead of below the rendered image.

How can I set the videomixer to not wait for incoming data from all streams? Or is it possible to get the videoscale plugin to send empty frames when no input data is available? Or do I have to write an application that regularly checks the available data on the udpsrc and dynamically links it to the mixer if data is available?

I also tried to add a queue/queue2 between the videoscale and the mixer to the pipeline but that didn't help either. I'm using GStreamer 1.4.5 on Ubuntu 15.04. Later everything will be ported to a custom embedded platform.

Thank you for your support and Best Regards

Stefan

Comment: Did you try compositor instead of videomixer?

Comment: Hi thiagoss, Thanks for your input. I just tried with compositor instead of videomixer, but the behaviour is identical.

Comment: Have successed finally?

Comment: Hi Mike, somehow, yes, we either solved or worked around it, but I don't have access to this project anymore; so I can't give you any details (it was with a previous employer long time ago)